# Display text in vertical align top with label in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Display text in vertical align top with label in bootstrap table cell the label text should be displayed in wrap

```html
<td>
  <span>16/12/2018 00:00:00</span>
  <p class="label label-danger" style="width:100px;line-height:normal;word-wrap:break-word;white-space: normal;">Some long text here like abcd smnopqurst xyz</p>
</td>
```

[image]

Comment: I think `label label-danger` not available in bootstrap 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`label label-danger` not available in bootstrap 4, use instead of `badge badge-danger`

`td` by default `vertical-align` is a `baseline`, so set `vertical-align` `top`

Add class `badge badge-danger mb-0` for `P`

```
<td>
  <span>16/12/2018 00:00:00</span>
  <p class="badge badge-danger mb-0" style="width:100px;line-height:normal;word-wrap:break-word;white-space: normal;">Some long text here like abcd smnopqurst xyz</p>
</td>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/7j89ze6f/8/

CSS

```
td{
  vertical-align:top;
}
td p.badge{
  vertical-align:top;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code.

```
<html>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span>16/12/2018 00:00:00</span>
                <p class="label label-danger" style="width:100px;line-height:normal;word-wrap:break-word;white-space: normal; display: block;">Some long text here like abcd smnopqurst xyz</p>
            </td>       
        </tr>
    </table>
    </html>
```

Comment: Sorry its not working the date should be displayed in the top of the cell and text and label should be in same line

Answer (score 0):

Please keep both elments span and Paragraph Tag inside a div and use the below css.

`div { display: flex; align-items: center;}`